# Can I Have A Hyper Link That Takes Me To An HREF #ID Upon The Click Of A Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

How Can I Have A Hyper Link That Takes Me To An HREF #ID Upon The Click Of A Button? I was initially trying to surround the button with an  tag but that wasn't working

Comment: try W3School or google for `ID location via href`

Comment: `<a href="#id">fragment link</a>`

Comment: you mean an <a name="ID">.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+button+links+to+id+on+page+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

`<a href="http://example.com/page.html#foo">Jump to #foo on page.html</a>`
will help you out. There should be a unique id on your page with the name `foo` to it.

if on the same page try `<a href="#foo">Jump to #foo on same page</a>`

There you can navigate without any hassles